# Will the coefficients of $n$ homogenous linear equations in $n$ variables necessarily be dependent on each-other?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given a set of $n$ variables $x_1,x_2\cdots x_n$, related by a set of homogenous linear equations relating each element to two others:

$x_1=Ax_p+Bx_q,$

$x_2=Cx_r+Dx_s$

$\vdots$

$ x_n=Yx_t+Zx_u$

Will there always be some non-trivial relation satisfied by the coefficients $A,B...$?

E.g. For the system of 2 equations: $x_1=Ax_1+Bx_2$ and $x_2=Cx_1+Dx_2$, we find $\frac{1-D}{C}=\frac{B}{1-A}$.

What methods could I use to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that every variable is expressed in terms of exactly two other variables is unnecessary. There is a much more general result. Namely, the system:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\ldots+a_{1n}x_n&=&0\\a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\ldots+a_{2n}x_n&=&0\\&\vdots&\\a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\ldots+a_{nn}x_n&=&0\end{array}$$

has a *non-trivial* solution in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ (i.e. a solution other than $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=0$) if and only if the [determinant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):

$$\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_n\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{vmatrix}$$

is **zero**. This is a very well-known theorem, and the proof is to be found in any linear algebra textbook.

For example, the $2\times 2$ determinant can be calculated using the formula $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}=ad-bc$.

As your example:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}x_1&=&Ax_1+Bx_2\\x_2&=&Cx_1+Dx_2\end{array}$$

can be transformed into:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}(1-A)x_1+(-B)x_2&=&0\\(-C)x_1+(1-D)x_2&=&0\end{array}$$

the condition for existence of a nontrivial solution is:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1-A&-B\\-C&1-D\end{vmatrix}=0$$

which is the same as $(1-A)(1-D)-BC=0$, which is (essentially) the same relation that you found.

Comment: Will the determinant always have a $\pm 1$ constant for the case about which I asked?

Comment: And is it possible for the determinant to be zero?

Comment: First question: yes, it corresponds to "naked" $x_i$'s (i.e. $\color{red}{1\cdot}x_i$'s) on the left side. Second question I don't understand fully. Do you want to ask whether all those variables on the right side can "cancel out" and you get a determinant which is always zero? Something like in a system $Ax+By=0$, $Ax+By=0$ (i.e. the same equation repeated twice)? (The determinant there is $AB-AB=0$ indeed, and a nontrivial solution in $x,y$ always exists.) Or, am I completely off the mark here?